# Overpunch Character conversion in unix

Tags: unix

Consider the 3rd column in the below pipe-separated file.

```
A001|akdfjhafa|0000000000034a|hello 
B001|bdfaakf|00000008754l|world 
B002|sdbvhjsdhg|00000829838{|consider 
C003|sdjfhjsdd|00000043724}|bracket
```

I need to convert the field to decimal values after overpunch character conversion

output should be

```
A001|akdfjhafa|3.41|hello 
B001|bdfaakf|-875.43|world 
B002|sdbvhjsdhg|82983.80|consider 
C003|sdjfhjsdd|-4372.40|bracket
```

Formula is simple

```
a=1 
b=2 
c=3 
... 
h=8 
i=9 
j=-1 
k=-2 
... 
q=-8 
r=-9 
{=0 
}=-0
```

Example:

```
00000043724} = -4372.40 
1234k = -123.42 
1234p = -123.47 
1234e = 123.45
```

My idea is as below

```
# replace {,a through 1 using below command. 
awk -F"|" '
  BEGIN {OFS="|"}
  { gsub("a", "1", $3);
    gsub("b", "2", $3);
    gsub("c", "3", $3);
    gsub("d", "4", $3);
    gsub("e", "5", $3);
    gsub("f", "6", $3);
    gsub("g", "7", $3);
    gsub("h", "8", $3);
    gsub("i", "9", $3);
    gsub("{", "0", $3);
    print $0
  }' test.dat
```

But when j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,} comes, I replace with corresponding numeric values and print $1,$2,"-"$3,$4.

After that, remove all leading zeroes.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does your code not give the result you want?

Comment: I don't know what the paragraphs of descriptive text under your code example are supposed to mean. Is this describing actual behavior as opposed to intended behavior? Extra behavior you don't know how to implement and haven't attempted? Something else?

Comment: @Andrew Medico: The code i used just replaces characters "a" through "i". I want to convert "j through "r" and "{" and "}". Also, leading zeroes need to be removed and value should be converted to decimal


Charles Duffy: Code under example is what i want to achieve. I don't know how to implement the same.

Comment: @ashokviswanathan, feedback on the implementation I've provided would be welcome. Do you have questions about how/why it works? Are you having difficulties running it? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a set of code which will temporarily help me.

Following code will replace "a" through "i" and "{" with corresponding positive values. 
gsub(/^0*/,"",$3) - Remove leading zeroes.
sed 's/..$/.&/;t;s/^.$/.0&/' - Adds a decimal before last 2 characters in the line.

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"}{gsub("a","1",$3);gsub("b","2",$3);gsub("c","3",$3);gsub("d","4",$3);gsub("e","5",$3);gsub("f","6",$3);gsub("g","7",$3);gsub("h","8",$3);gsub("i","9",$3);gsub(/^0*/,"",$3);print $1,$2,$4,$3}' test.dat| sed 's/..$/.&/;t;s/^.$/.0&/'|sed 's/[{]/0/g' > test1.dat
```

rm test

Following code will replace "j" through "r" and "}" with corresponding negative values and includes a special character(~) which will be used to filter data later and add '-'.

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"}{gsub("j","~1",$4);gsub("k","~2",$4);gsub("l","~3",$4);gsub("m","~4",$4);gsub("n","~5",$4);gsub("o","~6",$4);gsub("p","~7",$4);gsub("q","~8",$4);gsub("r","~9",$4); print}' test1.dat |sed 's/[}]/~0/g'>test2.dat

rm test1

grep -v "~" test2.dat > test3.dat

grep "~" test2.dat|sed 's/~//g'|awk -F"|" '{OFS="|";print $1,$2,$3,"-"$4}' >> test3.dat

rm test2

awk -F"|" '{OFS="|";print $1,$2,$4,$3}' test3.dat >test.dat

rm test3
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be implemented in native bash (not /bin/sh, but bash) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='|' read -r -a items; do
   text=${items[2]}
   [[ $text =~ [^1-9][0-9]+$ ]] && text=${BASH_REMATCH[0]} # strip leading 0s
   text=${text//a/1} text=${text//b/2} text=${text//c/3}
   text=${text//d/4} text=${text//e/5} text=${text//f/6}
   text=${text//g/7} text=${text//h/8} text=${text//i/9}
   text=${text//j/-1} text=${text//k/-2} text=${text//l/-3}
   text=${text//m/-4} text=${text//n/-5} text=${text//o/-6}
   text=${text//p/-7} text=${text//q/-8} text=${text//r/-9}
   text=${text//"{"/0} text=${text//"}"/-0}
   items[2]=$text                                   # write back to array
   printf -v output '%s|' "${items[@]}" # put all items in string with pipes after them
   printf '%s\n' "${output%'|'}"        # strip last pipe, print line with trailing newline
done <test.dat
```